Converting a 470-694Mhz TV antenna for 433Mhz reception
I'm working on a project which requires me to pick up LoRa signals that will be transmitted from a relatively low gain antenna. I've figured out that a large dipole would be idea for the receiver antenna. The issue is i cannot get a proper 433Mhz yagi dipole in a timely manner. However i can easily get a TV antenna (i have not been able to figure out the proper name for the exact design but i was able to find this picture.)
My main question how to tune it to 433Mhz. Additionally if someone knows the proper name for this style of antenna, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

remark: you say you can't get a 433 MHz dipole in time, but what you show is not a dipole antenna. You realize that a lamda/2 dipole is really not very glorious, right? it's two conductors that add up to – give or take 37 cm length, connected to a coax cable by means of some Balun. Impedance matching: yes, that will improve your receive strength by less than 3dB, and can be considered optional, for later addition.

It is not generally practical to convert an antenna for lower frequency operation. This is because, if you want to change the a given antenna design to a different frequency, what you do is scale it proportionally to the wavelength. So, to extend this antenna's range you would need to add to it, extending its overall size by 10% or so.
This is possible, but it'd likely be cheaper and easier to use wire and wood to make a suitable antenna from scratch. Receiving all the TV channels well requires a wide-band antenna, but since you're interested in low-bandwidth signals at 433 MHz in particular, you do not need a wide-band antenna, and a simple dipole or ground-plane antenna will do.

Additionally if someone knows the proper name for this style of antenna, please let me know.

It appears to be a corner reflector antenna with a Yagi array as the driven element.

Isn't that antenna a corner reflector?

@MikeWaters Thank you; I did not know that term.

Thank you for the information. For some reason i was hoping it would be possible to adjust it in some other way. I ended up getting a 433Mhz yagi antenna custom made by a local shop. Also thanks for the insight on the antenna type. I had been trying to figure it out (out of curiosity mostly) for months.
